# XSL Test Question, what is this testing?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have this line:

```
<xsl:when test="document('foo.xml')/field_config/field_rename/field[@old_name = $name]/@new_name">
```

foo.xml:

```
<field_config>
 <field_rename>
<field old_name="Modified" new_name="modification"/>
<field old_name="Created" new_name="creation"/>
</field_rename>
</field_config>
```

In general, what is this testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means:

*Exist an attribute named `new_name` for some `field` element having an attribute `old_name` equal to `$name` (var or param reference) and being child of `field_rename` and grand child of `field_config` root element in `foo.xml` document*

Answer (score 0):

If I read it correctly, it is testing for the "existence" of the following attribute.

```
foo.xml
  /field_config
    /field_rename
      /field[@old_name = $name]
        /@new_name
```

Which "reads" as (going backwards)...:

If there is a "new_name" attribute on a field node (where the attribute old_name = "someVariable") in a field_rename node, in a field_config node, in foo.xml... then do (whatever)